# How to remove proportion information from map view?

Tags: java, android, mapsforge

I'm using mapsforge in my project. By default proportion information is shown. How can I remove that? I mean this[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used MapForge before, but from the documentation the MapView has a method for getting the MapScaleBar with which you can use the setVisible() method to set its visibility.